# Angular JS + Opera Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, opera

In Angular JS app, if I clicked a link and change url location, Opera browser display non-interpolated strings (e.g. {{ name }}) on 300-400ms, after that all compile good.

In other browsers non-interpolated strings not display, all compile good. How fix this in Opera?

Comment: See [ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak).

Comment: Have you added style definitions?

Comment: without style defenitions not working too

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue. I've also added the ng-cloak directive to my css (loaded in the head) but I still get a flash of unstyled content.

Using [ng-bind](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind) however does work as a workaround (although I would prefer using ng-cloak).

Answer (score 0):

Opera mini is a proxy server, meaning it stripes some code (specially javascript code). You can read more [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/)

Angular seems to be more concentrating on modern android and IOS phone browsers which have a large share market in the developed cities.

But the y seem to be neglecting the developing market whose population use entry level phones. In my opinion, this should not be the case.

My advice, if your target users use opera mini make you web app accessible and functional even when javascript is disabled.